# Connecting two tables

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

I'm designing a database for a Cab/Taxi service. There's a table for taxi service details.

*cab_services*

```
+---------------------+
|  SID  |     Name    |
|---------------------|
|  S001 |   ABC Taxi  |
|  S002 |   XYZ Cabs  |
|  S003 |   MN Taxi   |
|  S004 |   OP Cabs   |
|_______|_____________|
```

And there's another table for locations.

*locations*

```
+-----------------------------------+
|  LID  |  Code  |     Location     |
|----------------|------------------|
|  L001 |   CO   |   Akarawita      |
|  L002 |   CO   |   Angamuwa       |
|  L003 |   CO   |   Batawala       |
|  L004 |   CO   |   Avissawella    |
|  L005 |   CO   |   Battaramulla   |
|  L006 |   GQ   |   Ambepussa      |
|  L007 |   GQ   |   Bemmulla       |
|  L008 |   GQ   |   Biyagama       |
|  L008 |   GQ   |   Alawala        |
|  L010 |   GQ   |   Andiambalama   |
|  L011 |   GQ   |   Biyagama IPZ   |
|  L012 |   KT   |   Bellana        |
|  L013 |   KT   |   Bolossagama    |
|  L014 |   KT   |   Bombuwala      |
|  L015 |   KT   |   Alutgama       |
|  L016 |   KT   |   Alubomulla     |
|_______|________|__________________|
```

Note that they are categorized according to districts. (**CO**, **GQ**, **KT**) Each district has multiple towns/cities.

A taxi service may be providing their service in multiple districts. And one district may have multiple taxi services. Its sort of a many to many scenario.

I'm trying to connect the cab_services table with the locations table. But I can't figure out how to. 
I would have done something like this if only one service was in on district.

```
+-------+-------------+---------+
|  SID  |     Name    |  Locs   |
|-------+-------------+---------|
|  S001 |   ABC Taxi  |   CO    |
|_______|_____________|_________|
```

But like I said before, a service can have many districts.

```
+-------+-------------+---------+
|  SID  |     Name    |  Locs   |
|-------+-------------+---------|
|  S001 |   ABC Taxi  |  CO, KT |
|_______|_____________|_________|
```

This would violate the 1NF.

I would want to be able to get results in a situation like say, if a user search using a Location name, he should get the cab services in that area.

What changes do I have to do in my database, table structure to accomplish this?

Please let me know if some part is confusing, I'll try my best to clarify it further. I'm pretty bad at explaining things. Thank you.

Comment: +1 for the nice and careful presentation of your question.

Comment: I agree with @stakx, though I would rather see those images in ascii text/markdown.

Comment: Thank you, @stakx and Oded. I edited the post and replaced the images with the ascii table structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your connecting table only needs to define the FK columns for the cab_services table and the locations table (i.e., Note what Oded states about duplication). So for example, if "ABC Taxi" is available in ALL "CO" locations then the connecting table would have the following records:

```
 SID | LID
-----------
S001 | L001
S001 | L002
S001 | L003
S001 | L004
S001 | L005
```

Comment: I did something close. I created another table with 2 columns. See [this](http://i.imgur.com/IzzME.png) image. And using [this](http://pastebin.com/rsywTuQ8) query I am able to get the desired results. Thank you.

Comment: Yes that seems like it works great with the assumption that a service will cover either all towns/cities in a given district or none. So is this not the answer? Why not accept this or Oded's response?

Comment: Yes, that's the only fuzzy part. But I can overlook that for now. This is not for a commercial application, just a pet project. :)

Answer (score 1):

You will have multiple entries on the connecting table.

```
SID   Name         Locs
-----------------------
S001  ABC Taxi     CO
S001  ABC Taxi     KT
```

This is still in 1NF, though you are duplicating data by having `SID` and `Name` in the table.

Comment: First off thank you. I see. But some other tables are also depending on the `cab_services` table. I'm keeping `SID` as the **PK** so doing this would mess things up. However I did something like this. I created another table with 2 columns. See [this](http://i.imgur.com/IzzME.png) image. And using [this](http://pastebin.com/rsywTuQ8) query I am able to get the desired results. This is avoid duplicate records in the `cab_services` table. Please let me know if there's a flaw in my modification.